# sitemap for laravel website with variable in slugs

Tags: javascript, php, xml, laravel-4, sitemap

I have a site developed using Laravel where a `URL` can be of this type-

```
xyz.com/search/{id}/{name}
```

Now, as you can see this `URL` has two variables which can be used to produce multiple `URLs` of the same type. For ex.-

```
xyz.com/search/1/katy

xyz.com/search/2/john
```

The site can have thousand of such URLs. I want to create a sitemap for my site. Definitely, it is not a good approach to add these URLs manually in a file by myself. I tried using some sitemap generation tools but they are not showing all the URLs in the sitemap. They are just showing the URLs for the links on homepage of the site. And that's the default nature of the tool afaik. They crawl the page and they go to the links present on the page. That's it! But the homepage has search functionality, where someone can choose from drop-down menu. And based on what they choose, the URL of the next page changes. I understand that the online tools that I tried might not be able to take this dynamic nature into consideration. So, how can I generate a sitemap which covers all the URLs for such a site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it using this package -

https://github.com/RoumenDamianoff/laravel-sitemap

and some guidance from this link -

http://www.laravel-tricks.com/tricks/adding-a-sitemap-to-your-laravel-application